# Performing math operations when plotting Pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: numpy, pandas

I'd like to plot products, ratios, etc of columns in a Pandas Data Frame without first creating a new column containing that product, ratio, etc. E.g.,

[df['A']/df['A']].plot()

doesn't work. For the following code:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['A','B','C'])
[df['A']/df['B']].plot()
```

I get the following error message: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'plot' "

Comment: **Doesn't work** is not a full problem description, please post sample data, code to create your df, the error and desired output

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added code and the specific error message.

Answer (score 5):

The division operation which you are doing in this line:

```
[df['A']/df['B']].plot()
```

returns a python list object instead of pandas object.

If you want to plot a particular column first without adding it to the dataframe, you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['A','B','C'])

df['A'].div(df['B']).plot()
```

which returns a `<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot>` object

Comment: `(df['A']/df['B']).plot()` would also work by the way. It becomes a list because the OP uses `[]` around the returning object to avoid dividing by a matplotlib object.

Comment: @ayhan Guess I missed on that. Thanks for reminding me :))